# Sorting a parent entity by an attribute of its children

Tags: sorting, core-data, relationship

I am currently working on an iOS app dealing with TV Shows and their Episodes. I have a one to many relationship setup (Show -> Episodes) and in the UITableView I want it to sort the Show entities by the next airing episode. I can't seem to figure it out. I have two different approaches I'm trying to no avail.

1. **Fetching Episodes**: Use an NSPredicate to only fetch episodes whos firstAired attribute is >= today, then sort by firstAired. When populating the tableview, I can access the Show attribute and pull needed data. While this is great, I end up with every episode that airs after today. I'm not seeing any way of only fetching the first episode to air after today.
2. **Fetching Shows**: Using an NSDate attribute(nextEpisodeDate) on the Show entity that is updated any time a new episode is added and any time the app is run. This means I have to update that attribute frequently(every 30 minutes that attribute can change if the episode just aired) and when I'm loading my tableview I have to locate the next episode to air on every cell which is intensive and slows down the tableview.

Does anyone know of an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it will be still efficient to do these steps:

1. Loop through each show and find the next upcoming episode. You can use the NSPredicate to filder by show, sort by the firstAired, and limit by 1 just to get the one you want.
2. Once you find the next upcoming episode for that particular show, add it into an NSMutableArray that will store all the upcoming episodes from each show.
3. Once we have got all the upcoming episode from each show, sort the NSMutableArray by firstAired.
4. Use the sorted episodes NSMutableArray as the data source of the table view and just get the show from the episodes.

I have built a similar app showing the next upcoming show from each TV channel, but the app I develop is designed to show the upcoming shows for each day, hence I have the benefit of limiting the firstAired >= today and firstAired <= next day.